# json object list sort using id column in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to sort my json data object before render the browser. this is the my json format

```
$scope.cityData= [
    {
        id: '520',
        city:'col01'
    },
    {
        id: '410',
        city:'col02'
    },
    {
        id: '412',
       city:'col03'
    }]
```

I tried to do it. but something wrong in my code.  I console log it. but did not sort

```
$scope.cityData.sort(function (a, b) { return a.id - b.id });
console.log($scope.cityData); 
$scope.newCitySort = $scope.cityData;
```

I need to assign this sorted data to new scope variable also. how i do this ?

Comment: What do you mean *"it did not sort"*? What was your actual output and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the actual $scope.cityData to be sorted. You can just use the [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter

In your html

```
<ul ng-repeat="city in cityData | orderBy: 'id' ">
  <li>**your list rendering code here**</li>
</ul>
```

And this will render your collections ordering it by id